# How can Puppet Exec logoutput without path

Tags: puppet

when use puppet exec, we can add logoutput to make it log exec output content,
but the output contains exec path like this:

> Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/SomeResource[1.1.1.1]/Exec[1.1.1.1]/returns: logout content

the path is too long and breaks original logoutput, how we can get a clean logoutput without "/Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/SomeResource[1.1.1.1]/" part

Comment: I don't really understand why you're concerned with formatting details of messages to the system log, but if you're not satisfied with the what `Exec` provides for you when `logoutput` is enabled then your alternative is to build your own logging into the command being executed.  You might use the `logger` command for that, for example.

Comment: @JohnBollinger could u add some document link for `logger`, basiclly, i use puppet apply xxx.pp to batch show some resources status through exec command with logoutput enabled, but the log content is break by the path

Comment: [`logger`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) is a standard Unix command.  I supposed that you're on some flavor of Unix, because the question doesn't really make sense for Windows logging.

Comment: I don't think logger can resolve my issue, what i want is when i run `puppet apply xx.pp`, xx.pp will exec my script, and logout script stdout to the console. Everything works except the logoutput contains a long "puppet path" which makes the logout unhuman readable

Comment: The format of the log output produced by Puppet is not configurable.  That's why I suggested `logger`, which would allow you to perform an end run around Puppet to write messages directly to the system log.  If that does not serve your particular scenario, then your other alternative is to postprocess the output to remove the unwanted text.  You might do that by filtering it with `sed`, for example.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for your help, may i redirect the exec log output to a file, and then use puppet notify to display a file content?

Comment: You certainly can redirect the output to a file.  Since you're using `puppet apply`, you should also be able to use a `Notify` resource to copy the contents of a local file into Puppet's output.  But note well that you will get the contents, if any, as of the time the catalog was *built*, before it is applied, so the result will not describe the current catalog run.